# How can I create mappings to execute specific Vim commands, depending on if a makefile exists?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, make

In general, I have makefiles setup anytime I'm working on C projects. To save and compile these projects, I've bound the *'* key to do this:

```
map ' :wa<CR>:!make<CR>
```

However, I sometimes open up test files that don't have a makefile, and want to compile those quickly as well:

```
map ' :wa<CR>:!gcc % -o %< && ./&<<CR>
```

My question is, how do I create a function to detect if a makefile exists, and then execute the appropriate command? The pseudocode would be the following:

```
If (makefile exists)
    run make
else
    run gcc on the single file
```

The only knowledge I have on the vimscript for it would be that I have to bind the ' key to a function. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Vim's `:make` command may also be of interest. It calls `make` by default but can be tweaked to call any command. Nice thing is it captures output and you can jump to errors.

Answer (score 6):

Wrap it into a function that should be called from your mapping, for instance:

```
func! MakeOrGcc()
    :write
    " check in the current working directory
    if filereadable('Makefile')
        :!make
    else
        :!gcc % -o %< && ./&<
    endif
endfunc

nnoremap ' :call MakeOrGcc()<CR>
```

Comment: Indeed, this way you could even use `findfile` if you need to search up a hierarchy. I would also mention `:make` in case the OP is not aware of it.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble there was `:make` before proposed edit which mentioned that OG wanted to use shell's `make` :)

Answer (score 4):

Since you're already executing a shell command, you could just use a shell `if` to test that condition:

```
map ' :wa<CR>:!if [ -f Makefile ]; then make; else gcc % -o %< && ./&<; fi<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, one doesn't need makefiles in order to use make. So it is as simple as

```
:make all
```

when you have a "standard" makefile; or

```
:make foobar
```

when you've got only `foobar.c`

Comment: `:make %<` to make current file